# Pre- calculus; Algebra; Trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> The instantaneous power $P$, measured in watts, in an AC circuit containing an inductance is given by
>   $$
> P = vi
> $$
>   where $t$ is the time in seconds, $i$ is the current in amperes and $v$ is the voltage in volts. Given that 
>   $$v = (120\cos\omega t)V$$
>   and 
>   $$i = (5\sin\omega t)A,$$ 
>   where $\omega$ is a constant,
>     (i)  find the period of $P$.
>     (ii) sketch one cycle of the graph of $P$.
>     (iii) describe the relationship between $P$ and $P_{1}$ where
>   $$
> P_{1} = P\left[ u(t) - u\left( t - \frac{\pi}{2\omega} \right) \right]
> $$

The answers are

> (i) Period of $P = \frac{\pi}{\omega}$ seconds.
>      (ii) [image]
>      (iii) $P_{1}$ is a unit step function of $P$. The function of $P$ is switched on at $t = 0$ and off at $t = \frac{\pi}{2\omega}$ seconds.

I'm extremely puzzled, it doesn't make any sense to me. I learnt somewhere that for the graphs
$$a\sin(bx-c)$$ 
and 
$$a\cos(bx-c),$$
the period is $2\pi/b$. But why is it $\omega/2$? Plus how do you get $300\sin2\omega t$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: Use the product-to-sum formula for $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $P = vi$ where $v = (120\cos\omega t)$ volts and $i = (5\sin\omega t)$ amperes. Thus we have
$$
P = (120\cos\omega t) \times (5\sin\omega t) = 600\sin\omega t\cos\omega t.
$$
Now recall that
$$
\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x,
$$
so we have
$$
600\sin\omega t\cos\omega t = 300\sin(2\omega t).
$$
To determine the period of this function, we need to solve
$$
\sin(2\omega t_{1}) = \sin(2\omega t_{2}).
$$
Remember, the period is how long it takes for the graph to be the same again, which is why we have the above equivalence. The $\sin(x)$ function has a period of $\color{red}{2\pi}$, so
$$
\sin(2\omega t_{1}) = \sin(2\omega t_{2}) \iff 2\omega t_{1} - 2\omega t_{2} = \color{red}{2\pi} \iff t_{1} - t_{2} = \frac{2\pi}{2\omega} = \frac{\pi}{\omega}.
$$
Thus the period of $300\sin(2\omega t)$ is $\pi/\omega$ seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**About the units**

In the international system of units (SI units):

A volt (V) is the measure of electric potential, that is, energy per unit charge.  Energy is measures in Joules (J).  Charge is measured in Coulombs (C).  Hence, 
$$\text{V} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{C}}$$

An Ampere (A) is the measure of current, that is, charge per unit time.  Charge is measured in Coulombs (C).  Time is measured in seconds (s).  Hence,
$$\text{A} = \frac{\text{C}}{\text{s}}$$

A Watt (W) is the measure of power, that is, energy per unit time.  Energy is measured in Joules (J).  Time is measured in seconds (s).  Hence, 
$$\text{W} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}}$$

Thus,
$$\text{VA} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{C}} \cdot \frac{\text{C}}{\text{s}} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{s}} = \text{W}$$

**The problem**

We are given that $P = vi$, where $v = 120\cos(\omega t)~\text{V}$ and $i = 5\sin(\omega t)~\text{A}$.  Hence, 
\begin{align*}
P & = [120\sin(\omega t)~\text{V}][5\sin(\omega t)~\text{A}]\\
  & = 600\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)~\text{VA}\\
  & = 600\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)~\text{W}
\end{align*}
The double angle formula for sine is 
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
P & = 600\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)~\text{W}\\
  & = 300 \cdot 2\sin(\omega t)\cos(\omega t)~\text{W}\\
  & = 300\sin(2\omega t)~\text{W}
\end{align*}
which has the form $P = a\sin(b t)$ with $a = 300$ and $b = 2\omega$.  Thus, the period is 
$$P = \frac{2\pi}{b} = \frac{2\pi}{2\omega} = \frac{\pi}{\omega}$$